# Is there a way to "freely" position an item inside a flexbox regardless of the other items positions?

Tags: html, css

I'm making as practice a navigation menu that includes a search bar on it, the problem is that I can't figure out how to better position the menu and the search bar. They are inside a flexbox so their positioning are linked to the space among the items right? Is there a way to position the search bar all the way to the right, but it would still be responsive?

Is it worth to make a navigation menu using flexbox? If not, is there a better way ?

Here's what I'm trying to do

https://css-tricks.com/

I've tried setting the search-bar's container to position absolute and the flex container to relative but it breaks the whole thing.

Also I've tried removing the bar from the flex container, but I can't align the search bar with the menu items or center it regarding the nav container.

Here's what I got

***HTML***

```
<nav>
      <div class="nav_home">
        <a href="#">
          Home
        </a>
      </div>
        <ul class="links">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Generic</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Text</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Here</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="searchbar">
            <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="" placeholder="Search..">
        </div>          
      </nav>
```

```
nav{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 70px;
    background-color: #984E6D;
    font-size: 30px;
    border: 2px solid #ff80df;
}

nav a{
    color: #FBEAFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px #888888;
    transition: 0.1s ease-in;
}

nav a:hover{
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.57);
    text-shadow: 2px 2px rgba(136, 136, 136, 0.5);
}

.links{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 350px;
}

.links li{
    list-style: none;
    transition: 0.1s;
}

#myInput{
    padding: 5px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Ryenra/dm2eu3vL/12/

Comment: Not very clear the expected result.. Probably you'll need to change `justify-content: space-around;` to `justify-content: space-between;` And after that play with responsiveness

Comment: Sorry my bad, what I'm trying to do is placing only the search bar to the far right without modifying the position of the other items in the nav menu

Comment: So first of all you should push edge items to the corners (space-between) and after that start moving them with margins/paddings. it's the best way here. You really don't need floating space on the left/right sides.

Answer (score 0):

Well you did everything right you just need to add `margin-left:auto` in .searchbar .

```css
nav{
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-around;
 align-items: center;
 min-height: 70px;
 background-color: #984E6D;
 font-size: 30px;
 border: 2px solid #ff80df;
}

nav a{
 color: #FBEAFF;
 text-decoration: none;
 letter-spacing: 0.5px;
 text-shadow: 2px 2px #888888;
 transition: 0.1s ease-in;
}

nav a:hover{
 color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.57);
 text-shadow: 2px 2px rgba(136, 136, 136, 0.5);
}

.links{
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-around;
 width: 350px;
}

.links li{
 list-style: none;
 transition: 0.1s;
}

#myInput{
 padding: 5px;
}

.searchbar{
  margin-left:auto;
}
```

```html
<nav>
      <div class="nav_home">
        <a href="#">
          Home
        </a>
      </div>
        <ul class="links">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Generic</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Text</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Here</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="searchbar">
            <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="" placeholder="Search..">
        </div>          
      </nav>
```

so search box leave all the space from left side and will go to right .

Comment: It does put the search bar all the way to the right but it affects the other items as well pushing them to the left, what I was looking for is to position only the search bar to the right without modifying the position of the other items

Comment: you can use margin-right:20px; for align the element from left side , it wont effect other elements

Answer (score 0):

```css
nav{
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-around;
 align-items: center;
 min-height: 70px;
 background-color: #984E6D;
 font-size: 30px;
 border: 2px solid #ff80df;
}

nav a{
 color: #FBEAFF;
 text-decoration: none;
 letter-spacing: 0.5px;
 text-shadow: 2px 2px #888888;
 transition: 0.1s ease-in;
}

nav a:hover{
 color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.57);
 text-shadow: 2px 2px rgba(136, 136, 136, 0.5);
}

.links{
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-around;
 width: 350px;
  margin: auto;
}

.links li{
 list-style: none;
 transition: 0.1s;
}

#myInput{
 padding: 5px;
}

.link-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex: 2 0 auto;
}

.nav_home, .searchbar {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  margin: auto;
}

.searchbar {
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
      <div class="nav_home">
        <a href="#">
          Home
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class= "link-wrapper">
        <ul class="links">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Generic</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Text</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Here</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div> 
       
        <div class="searchbar">
            <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="" placeholder="Search..">
        </div>          
      </nav>
```